# android layouts in LinearLayout overlap on devices with on-screen navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

When my app is downloaded onto a device with the on-screen navigation tab, some of my layouts start to overlap each other.

Basically, I have a parent vertical `LinearLayout` with four other `LinearLayout` as children. The children layouts start overlapping each other when the navigation is on the screen.

Is this normal? I thought that since I used the default Android widgets then it shouldn't have an overlapping problem.

The initialization code:

```
  // other code ... 

  mainLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
  mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

  // other code...

  titleBarLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
  titleBarLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  mainLayout.addView(titleBarLayout);

  titleBarLayout.getLayoutParams().width =SCREEN_WIDTH;

  // other code...

  miniBarLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
  miniBarLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
  miniBarLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  miniBarLayout.setPadding(0, 1, 0, 1);
  mainLayout.addView(miniBarLayout);

  // other code...

  userBarLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
  userBarLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

  mainLayout.addView(userBarLayout);
```

Specific problem: the `userBarLayout` overlaps with the `miniBarLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sum of the sizes of the Views (or Widgets) you are putting next to each other on screen becomes bigger than the available space, something has to give.. There are several options to deal with this problem:

- Use RelativeLayouts to position Views relative to other Views, thereby giving Android better hints on how to deal with lacking screen space for your app.
- Define the sizes of your Views/Widgets in such a way that you have some "spare" space. Usually you will need the "weight" and "weightSum" properties of a View to define what you want to do with this "spare" space. In other words: define sizes of your Views in a relative manner. (note: when using weights, understand that those only apply to SPARE space, after all fixed sizes are accounted for, so you may want to deliberately set all sizes of your Views to 0dp and then define everything with relative weights!)
- If you truly want to define your layouts in "hard" numbers (like dp's), you may need to create separate layout xml files for specific devices/device categories. Those layout files should then be stored in attributed resource directories (/res/layout-large /res/layout-w700dp etc)

Comment: Sounds good, but I didn't hardcode anything except for the width of the title bar and the views aren't completely full of other views, so there should be "spare" space. I'll try what you suggested and get back to this answer.

Comment: If you want to know which of the Views in your main layout is taking too much space, you could use the HierarchyViewer to take a look at the values for measuredHeight/layoutHeight for your mainLayout and children. That would probably give you more insight. Maybe there is a layout parameter that you accidentally set to the wrong value, or one of the images you are wrapping (just guessing here) is too big/in wrong resource folder. Etc, etc. HierarchyViewer should be accessible from your IDE and you can also run it from the 'tools' directory in your android-sdk.